# PHP : Joomla:- File upload issue issue in "iPhone devices" (Uploading the same image from different file upload fields) while working fine on desktop

Tags: php, html, ios, iphone, joomla

I am facing an issue on all iPhone devices (iphone 4, 5, 6 & iPad).
I have created a page:

> http://joomla.iworklab.com/aquadam_newtheme/index.php/rfq-construction-stage/constructionstageform

On this page, there many file upload fields but only three file upload fields are taken the same image on iphone devices & others file uploads fields are working fine. File upload fields, those taken same image are given below:

```
    <input type="file" name="jform[select_picture1_bt]" id="select_picture1_bt" accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/bmp,application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
aria-invalid="false">

<input type="file" name="jform[select_picture2_bt]" id="select_picture2_bt" accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/bmp,application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">

<input type="file" name="jform[select_picture3_bt]" id="select_picture3_bt" accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/bmp,application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">
```

Only these three fields are uploading the same image on server while remaining fields are working fine.

I have attached the snapshot of fields those are creating same image issue in iphone devices as given below:
[image]

& snapshot of remaining fields on same page, those are working fine on all devices (including iphone) as given below:
[image]

Please suggest anyone, how can I fixed this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the exact cause of this issue:

> "In iphone, all the file upload inputs will automatically set with
>   image name 'image.jpg' so when you uploading image in same destination
>   folder then it will pointed to same image."

Hence final solution for it, is either you use unique time stamp with image name at the end of image upload (like: md5(microtime(true)), or md5(rand(true))) or use different destination name for each image.